# Multibyte characters in JSON lost when saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, utf-8, multibyte, hstore

I convert my hash to JSON using Rails' .to_json() method.

Hash:

```
{ "Größe" => "XL" }
```

JSON:

```
"{\"Gr\\u00f6\\u00dfe\":\"XL\"}"
```

After that the JSON string is stored in a hstore (Postgres) column called **static** by this Rails (3.2.6) SQL command:

```
UPDATE ... "static" = 'options=>"{\"Gr\u00f6\u00dfe\":\"XL\"}"' WHERE ...
```

*There is already one escaping backslash missing.*

In the database itself the **static** column looks like this:

```
"options"=>"{\"Gru00f6u00dfe\":\"XL\"}"
```

*All backslashes for **u00f6** and **u00dfe** have gone.*

JSON.parse() doesn't identify the multibyte characters any more, so it returns the following hash:

```
{ "Gru00f6u00dfe" => "XL" }
```

Has anyone an idea how to prevent this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, rails doesn't support PostgreSQL's hstore. But fix is easy, just Use [`activerecord-postgres-hstore`](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-postgres-hstore) gem. Using `activerecord-postgres-hstore` will free you from serialization or encoding issues.  here is how

1) Install the gem & then Change *static* column type to hstore

```
class ChangeHStoreDateTypeInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   change_column :my_table, :static, :hstore
  end
```

2) Add index

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_gin_static ON my_table USING GIN(static);
```

3) Now, you can instantiate the model entity & Update the values as you normally would without worrying about serialization or encoding.

```
@model.static["Größe"] = "XL"
```

More info: https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this problem seems to be caused by the JSON encoding. Since it's an multidimensional array, I would like to use JSON for serialization.

Since Postgres 9.2 came out same days ago, I will try to solve it with the new JSON data type directly.